# How can I prevent close session/shutdown/reboot when certain console program is executing?

Tags: unity, gnome, power-management, policykit

I want to disable close session/shutdown/reboot from Gnome (Unity/Lightdm) when `lftp` is executing.

Is there any way? Perhaps with polkit?